# How to save stdout.read() in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, paramiko

Guys I am struggling to figure out how to save output of a command I ran to a csv file. Here is the code i have written so far to get the output from a linux host using paramiko modue.

```
ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=ip,port=22,username=user_name,password=passwd)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("some random command")
output = (stdout.read().decode(encoding='ascii'))
print(output)
```

This is the output I get:

```
Lun VV_WWN                           VVName                   HostName     
1 600525465446418gsdhgdfhahf14488454 HOST-California_westcos domain123
9 600525465446418gsdhgdfhahf14488454 HOST-Texas_westcos      domain123
4 600525465446418gsdhgdfhahf14488454 HOST-Kasnsas_westcos    domain123
4 600525465446418gsdhgdfhahf14488454 HOST-Ohio_westcos       domain123
7 600525465446418gsdhgdfhahf14488454 HOST-Nevada_westcos     domain123
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
5                                                  total
```

I need to remove header and footer and save this file as CSV. Any suggestion on how can i achieve this. 
I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
import csv
split = output.split('\n')
keep = split[1:-3]
word_split = [k.split() for k in keep]
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(word_split)
```

Comment: Oh man ! This worked like magic. Thank you so much. You saved my so much of time. Many Thanks !

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the csv builtin python package.

just add the following code:

```
import csv

lines = list(output.splitlines())
lines = lines[1:-2]

with open('my_csv.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    my_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for line in lines:
        my_writer.writerow(line[0].split())
```

good luck and let me know if you need more help.
Some reference can be found here: [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I am getting this error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines`

Comment: @Sunita Hi Sunita, I fixed the code in the body of the message.